# How pass the asp.net session token from page to page?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state

best and secured way to pass the asp.net session token from page to page. 
1. cookies (not secured)
2. url (not secured)
3. hidden fields ?
using hidded fields is right way to pass ?
how to pass using hidded fileds?
how to disble the session token in cookies and also in url (session state conguration)?

Answer (score 0):

From my answer for similar question, "[securing ASP.NET forms authentication token on client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266705/securing-asp-net-forms-authentication-token-on-client-side/3266814#3266814)" :

**Session:**

[Fast, Scalable, and Secure Session State Management for Your Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163730.aspx#S9)